# Parse.com: How do I set Access-Control-Allow-Origin for public resources?

Tags: parse-platform

I want to let my project's JS/CSS requested by other domains for bookmarklet use, but I got an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error.

Have searched `parse.com Access-Control-Allow-Origin` keywords. Nothing helpful. Wish there's a way to make it...

Comment: have you fixed it? I have the same issue, no solution found so far.

Comment: I have same problem. No idea

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34328319/how-to-save-an-image-from-website-to-parse-com-backend-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Your server would read the `Origin` header that comes from the client, check against a list of accepted domains and then include that domain in a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response.

According to the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header):

> The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header indicates whether a resource
>   can be shared based by returning the value of the Origin request
>   header, "*", or "null" in the response. ABNF:
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" ":"
>   origin-list-or-null | "*"

Here is more information:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS